# How to update dataset in R

Tags: r, join, updates

Df1:

```
ID   Score   Test
1     97        1
1     98        2 
2     85        1
2     NA        2
3     NA        1
3     79        2
```

Df2:

```
ID   Score      Test
2    70           2
3    60           1
```

Desired result:

```
ID   Score   Test
1     97        1
1     98        2 
2     85        1
2     70        2
3     60        1
3     79        2
```

I actually have a larger dataframe and a total of 5 tests. I want to update the NA scores in DF1 using the scores in DF2.
How do I do this in R?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does this work:

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% left_join(df1, by = c('ID','Test')) %>% 
   mutate(Score = coalesce(Score.x, Score.y)) %>% 
   select(-2,-4) %>% relocate(1,3,2)
# A tibble: 6 x 3
     ID Score  Test
  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1     1    97     1
2     1    98     2
3     2    85     1
4     2    70     2
5     3    60     1
6     3    79     2
```

Comment: what it Score.x, Score.y ?

Comment: We are only using 'ID' and 'Test' for joining two tables and because we are not using "score" column to join, and it's present in both dataframes, it creates score.x for first dataframe, and score.y for second. we are not including that in our final result using select(-2,-4) which refers to these very columns